# Which Boost library packages needed for avro c++

Tags: c++, linux, boost, avro

I have  installed all the packages of boost 1.64 in linux. but I want to install only those packages which needed for avro.
here are the boost library

```
./b2 --show-libraries
  - atomic
  - chrono
  - container
  - context
  - coroutine
  - coroutine2
  - date_time
  - exception
  - fiber
  - filesystem
  - graph
  - graph_parallel
  - iostreams
  - locale
  - log
  - math
  - metaparse
  - mpi
  - program_options
  - python
  - random
  - regex
  - serialization
  - signals
  - system
  - test
  - thread
  - timer
  - type_erasure
  - wave
```

where as `avro` says it needs following packages.(avro package is avro-cpp-1.8.2)
libboost-dev
libboost-filesystem-dev
libboost-system-dev
libboost-program-options-dev.

I not sure here what is libboost-dev package in boost? Which library from boost I have to install for this package.

Comment: I’m doing manual installation of boost library and avro. Since I don’t have root permission so I’m following below instructions to install boost and avro.

./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/home/work/boost
./b2 install --prefix=/home/work/boost --without-python

Currently I’m not able to figure out which libraries is required for avro so I’m installing all boost library.

Avro installation 
BOOST_ROOT=/home/work/boost; export BOOST_ROOT; 
export DESTDIR==/home/work/avro; ./build.sh install

can some please answer

Comment: can someone  please answer ?